# C# middle layer app.config file went missing when published

Tags: c#, app-config

I’ve created a small console application with the 3 tire architecture, the UI Layer, service layer and the data access layer. And also it contains another layer the domain layer which sits Vertically so all the main 3 layers can access the domain layer. I’ve put the connection strings, logger paths etc. in the Domain project’s properties settings section which automatically entered in the app.config file of the domain project. This is what exactly I want, other layers can access the global variables and objects in the domain layer and I can change the settings in the domain layer through the app.config file of the domain layer.

The problem is when I published the console application, the app.config file of the domain layer was missing. Now I want be able to change the configuration settings. How can I get the app.config file of the domain layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use app.config from class library projects.  Any app settings that your various layers use need to be defined in the app.config file of the actual executable(s).

In your case it seems like the best solution is just to copy the domain layer's app.config to the console application's output.  You can set the build process to do this automatically (set `Build Action` to "Content" and `Copy to Output Directory` to "Copy Always").  Just keep in mind that then it will overwrite any configuration settings you may have defined in the console application project itself.